# How to apply forEach();

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, foreach

So, i am making a quiz game and i want to generate answers from an array, I tried some solutions but it doesn't work, So i need your solutions to my code.

 *here is Const*

```
const shekitxva = [
{
    questions: 'What was created first',
    answers:[
        {text: 'Egg', correct: 'false'},
        {text: 'Chicken', correct: 'true'},
        {text: 'Eleniko', correct: 'false'},
        {text: 'Computer', correct: 'false'}

    ]
}
```

]

Here is question display

```
kitxva.innerText = shekitxva[0].questions;
```

So how to dispaly those answers to div elements

**javascript**

```
var pasuxebi = document.querySelectorAll('.pasuxebi');
var checkBtn = document.querySelector('.check');
var nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next');
var startBtn = document.querySelector('.start');
var kitxva = document.querySelector('h3');
var pasuxebiBox = document.querySelector('.pasuxebi');
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="box">
    <h3 class="none">Question</h3>
<div class="pasuxebi none">
    <div class="pasuxi">pirveli</div>
    <div class="pasuxi">pirveli</div>
    <div class="pasuxi">pirveli</div>
    <div class="pasuxi">pirveli</div>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
    <div class="start">Start</div>
    <div class="check none">Check</div>
    <div class="next none">Next</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? This can't be all your code, or is it?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is a meaningless statement. What happens *exactly*? Which code gives which results exactly, an what is wrong about those results? What results exactly would you want instead? Please **[edit]** the question and clarify. Also, it helps if you **use only English names** for things in your code, so we can at least have a guess at what `pasuxi` and `pirveli` are doing so many times in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to validate the answers in the back-end , as user can see your front-end codes , you shouldn't show which answer is correct , to loop between your element you can do something like this :

```
    const shekitxva = [
    {
        questions: 'What was created first',
        answers: [
            { text: 'Egg', correct: 'false' },
            { text: 'Chicken', correct: 'true' },
            { text: 'Eleniko', correct: 'false' },
            { text: 'Computer', correct: 'false' }
        ]
    }
]
let quAnswers = shekitxva[0].answers;
var pasuxebi = document.querySelectorAll('.pasuxi');
for (i=0;i<quAnswers.length ; i++) {
    pasuxebi[i].innerHTML = quAnswers[i].text ;
}
```

you need to assign a name parameter to your answers container ( like assigning `data-value` ) and send the chosen answer with container name to back-end to validate , but do not  show which one is correct , even in your javascript , because users can see it . as you want to know how to loop and generate answers texts ,  above code gives you the clue
if you have more than 1 question , you should loop through parents and then access the children , using their index to access your array and it's objects

Answer (score 0):

you can use the map fonction on an array to map through an array like "foreach"

```
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];
// pass a function to map
const map1 = array1.map(x => x * 2);
console.log(map1);
// expected output: Array [2, 8, 18, 32]
```

so you can do something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <h1>My First Web Page</h1>
    <p>My First Paragraph</p>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        const shekitxva = [
            {
                questions: 'What was created first',
                answers: [
                    { text: 'Egg', correct: 'false' },
                    { text: 'Chicken', correct: 'true' },
                    { text: 'Eleniko', correct: 'false' },
                    { text: 'Computer', correct: 'false' }

                ]
            },
            {
                questions: 'What was created second',
                answers: [
                    { text: 'Egg', correct: 'false' },
                    { text: 'Chicken', correct: 'true' },
                    { text: 'Eleniko', correct: 'false' },
                    { text: 'Computer', correct: 'false' }

                ]
            },
            {
                questions: 'What was created third',
                answers: [
                    { text: 'Egg', correct: 'false' },
                    { text: 'Chicken', correct: 'true' },
                    { text: 'Eleniko', correct: 'false' },
                    { text: 'Computer', correct: 'false' }

                ]
            }


        ]
        let inputs = '';
        shekitxva.map(qst => {
            inputs += '<h3>' +  qst.questions + '</h3>';
            qst.answers.map(ans => {
                inputs += '<p>' + ans.text + ' is ' + ans.correct + '<p>';
            })
        })
        document.getElementById('demo').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', inputs);
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```